# QSqlTableModel: Unable to find table not working on newer database

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

I'm either very confused about what I'm doing or something is wrong.

I'm upgrading from postgresql 8 to 16. I want to connect to my PostgreSQL database and select a table.

Here is the minimal reproducible example of what I'm doing:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlTableModel>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setPort(5432);
    db.setDatabaseName("myDatabase");
    db.setUserName("postgres");
    db.setPassword("");

    // Open the database
    if (!db.open()) {
        cout << "Error: " << db.lastError().text().toStdString();
        return 1;
    }

    // Output databases
    QStringList tables = db.tables(QSql::Tables);
    foreach(const QString & table, tables) {
        cout << "Table Name: " << table.toStdString() << endl;
    }

    // Select Table
    QSqlTableModel model;
    model.setTable("spatial_ref_sys");

    cout << "Error: " << model.lastError().text().toStdString();

    db.close();
    return a.exec();
}
```

When running the code it print a list of table:

> Table Name: spatial_ref_sys
> Table Name: schema1.table1
> Table Name: schema1.table2
> Table Name: schema2.table1
> ...
> Error:  Unable to find table spatial_ref_sys

---

This error only shows when I'm running my new PostgreSQL 16 database but not on my PostgreSQL 8 database

Comment: Looks like you are missing the extension `postgis'. If possible check your v8 it and the schema in which it is installed (default public). You should be able it get it in v16 via [create extenion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) postgis.

Comment: I created the database during the POSTGIS installation. So i expect it was installed by default. The two database also look exactly the same in pgadmin

Comment: I checked right now. I get a `ERROR:  extension "postgis" already exists` message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a know [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-79033). I was using an older version of Qt5 so I updated to the latest one.